# DISTINCT keyword is not working when I using the PHP MySQL query

Tags: php, mysql

When I using the PHP MySQL query DISTINCT keyword is not working
here is my PHP query store data into JSON format

```
<?php
include("connection.php");
$uid=$_REQUEST['userid'];
$activityname="Change status";
$recentstatus=mysqli_query($cn,"SELECT DISTINCT userstatus,activityid,userid FROM useractivity WHERE userid='$uid' AND activityname='$activityname' ORDER BY activityid DESC ");
while($raw=mysqli_fetch_assoc($recentstatus))
{
    $emparray[] = $raw;      
}
$x['data'][]=$emparray;
$x['status']='OK';
echo json_encode($emparray);  
?>
```

Comment: Looks fine to me. This returns every distinct combination of userstatus,activityid, and userid

Comment: What is your table structure? Paste it here along some dummy data.

Comment: Do you know DISTINCT works only for entire column set? So, if you have three records: [dog|Billy, dog|Johnny, cat|Billy], SELECT DISTINCT animal, name will select them all, because it seeks for unique COMBINATION of animal and name.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to remove duplicates then use DISTINCT. GROUP BY should be used to apply aggregate operators to each group

[GROUP BY v DISTINCT](http://msmvps.com/blogs/robfarley/archive/2007/03/24/group-by-v-distinct-group-by-wins.aspx)

Comment: A fact which is not obvious from that link. !?!